# PHP Multiples values for one array - Using date

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get the next dates with month, day and year.

To be exact, I get a variable which will be the amount of months I will fetch. In this case, it is `$p`, from there I loop to get the dates and save them in an array. Ok until then.

Using foreach I try to take the values ​​and move to variables, `$val1`, `$val2`, `$val3`, `$val4`.

**The problem** is the output, always repeats what I need the same number of times as `$p` value.

Exit Example:

```
2019-11-18
2019-12-18
2020-01-18
2020-02-182019-11-18
2019-12-18
2020-01-18
2020-02-182019-11-18
2019-12-18
2020-01-18
2020-02-182019-11-18
2019-12-18
2020-01-18
2020-02-18




$dateNew = date("d-m-Y");
$dataConvert = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dateNew));//
$p=4;//Numbers of months to add
$i=0;//Test value 

$datas=array();
while($i<$p){
    $x = strtotime($dataConvert );
    $n = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+$i month",$x));
    $datas[] = $n;
    $i++;
}
//var_dump($datas);

foreach ($datas as $value) {
    $val1 = $datas[0];
    $val2 = $datas[1];      
    $val3 = $datas[2];
    $val4 = $datas[3];
    echo $val1;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $val2;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $val3;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $val4;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, kindly post some more clarification.

Comment: could you post the data you are working with (array), the actual output and expected output?

Comment: Why do you want to assign the variables to `$val1` etc?  As for getting the same values `$val1 = $datas[0];` will always give the same date as it is not influenced by the `foreach()` but always sets the value from the original array.

Comment: Are you asking how to build an array of dates?

Comment: lovelace my output of array is = array(4) { [0]=> string(10) "2019-11-18" [1]=> string(10) "2019-12-18" [2]=> string(10) "2020-01-18" [3]=> string(10) "2020-02-18" } 2019-11-18.
I need pass val of array(4) [0] for one variable "x". 
Example: x=2019-11-18
                y=2019-12-18...

Comment: Nigel Ren, Exactly.
I need to pass array values ​​to variables that I can use, not just print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$dateNew = date("d-m-Y");
$dataConvert = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dateNew));//
$p=4;//Numbers of months to add
$i=0;//Test value 

$datas=array();
while($i<$p){
    $x = strtotime($dataConvert );
    $n = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+$i month",$x));
    $datas[] = $n;
    $i++;
}

foreach ($datas as $value) {
    echo $value;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Your issue is happening, because you are not using the `foreach` properly. You code is made for not using a loop whatsoever.

If you replace the loop with only its body like this:

```
$val1 = $datas[0];
$val2 = $datas[1];      
$val3 = $datas[2];
$val4 = $datas[3];
echo $val1;
echo '<br>';
echo $val2;
echo '<br>';
echo $val3;
echo '<br>';
echo $val4;
```

It will work as you expect for exactly 4 months. But if you want to use it for a different values, you have to write a proper loop like the one above. You can read some more about foreach loops [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and about loops in PHP in general [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_loop_types.htm)

Comment: Thanks for help and show the way of studies. This is very valuable for those who are learning.
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing values in foreach `foreach ($datas as $value)` This line means that every value that is in `$datas` variable, will be represented as `$value` inside the foreach block, one for each loop. So if you want to print them all, you don't need to use original `$datas` variable. You could just do:

```
foreach ($datas as $value) {
echo $value;
echo "<br/>";
}
```

This will print all items in `$datas` array followed by a HTML line break. If you are not sure how foreach works, please be sure to read [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 0):

Array outpup:

```
 array(4) { [0]=> string(10) "2019-11-18" [1]=> string(10) "2019-12-18" [2]=> 
    string(10) "2020-01-18" [3]=> string(10) "2020-02-18" }
```

I used the:

```
echo '<br>';
echo $ val;
```

As an example, my fault.
Within the loop I wanted to pass array values ​​to variables.
example

```
foreach ($ dates as $ value) {
    $ val1 = $ dates [0];//=>Pass value of array(4) { [0] to $val1//
    $ val2 = $ dates [1];//=>Pass value of array(4) { [1] to $val2//
    $ val3 = $ dates [2];//=>Pass value of array(4) { [2] to $val3//
    $ val4 = $ dates [3];//=>Pass value of array(4) { [3] to $val4//

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was solved.
Just get $dates [0], $dates [1],
...

```
<?php
$servername = "mysql.srv.local";
$username = "test";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "newdb";
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

$dateNew = date("d-m-Y");
$dataConvert = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dateNew));//
$p=10;//Numbers of months to add
$i=0;//Test value 

$datas=array();
while($i<$p){
    $x = strtotime($dataConvert );
    $n = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+$i month",$x));
    $datas[] = $n;
    $i++;
}
//var_dump($datas);//Output values of array = array(10) { [0]=> string(10) "2019-11-18" [1]=> string(10) "2019-12-18" [2]=> string(10) "2020-01-18" [3]=> string(10) "2020-02-18" [4]=> string(10) "2020-03-18" [5]=> string(10) "2020-04-18" [6]=> string(10) "2020-05-18" [7]=> string(10) "2020-06-18" [8]=> string(10) "2020-07-18" [9]=> string(10) "2020-08-18" }
echo '<br>';
$val1 = $datas[0];
$val2 = $datas[1];
$val3 = $datas[2];
$val4 = $datas[3];
$val5 = $datas[4];
$val6 = $datas[5];
$val7 = $datas[6];
$val8 = $datas[7];
$val9 = $datas[8];
$val10 = $datas[9];
echo $val1;
echo '<br>';
echo $val2;
echo '<br>';
echo $val3;
echo '<br>';
echo $val4;
echo '<br>';
echo $val5;
echo '<br>';
echo $val6;
echo '<br>';
echo $val7;
echo '<br>';
echo $val8;
echo '<br>';
echo $val9;
echo '<br>';
echo $val10;

$addDatesForTest = " INSERT INTO `datesTest` (`test1`, `test2`, `test3`, `test4`, `test5`, `test6`, `test7`, `test8`, `test9`, `test10`)  VALUES ('$val1', '$val2', '$val3', '$val4', '$val5', '$val6', '$val7', '$val8', '$val9', '$val10')";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
          // Check connection
          if ($conn->connect_error) {
              die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
          }


          if($conn->query($addDatesForTest) === TRUE){
            echo "";
            ;

          }else{
            echo "Error: ". $addDatesForTest. "<br>" . $conn->error;
            $conn->close();
          }
?>
```

Add values in mysql db for test, and select all values:

```
select * from `datesTest`;
id,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7,test8,test9,test10
1,2019-11-18,2019-12-18,2020-01-18,2020-02-18,2020-03-18,2020-04-18,2020-05-18,2020-06-18,2020-07-18,2020-08-18
```

Thank you all for your help.
Hugs, sorry for taking your time.